# get server relative url of file in sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint

how can you get the server relative url of a file in a document library from code in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
item.File.ServerRelativeUrl
```

or if you you don´t work with files:

```
item[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileRef].ToString();
```